# Test async.waterfall in node.js with sinon.js timers

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, async.js

I have the following function that I wish to be tested which use async.js heavily in it:

```
MyClass.prototype.pipeline = function(arg1, arg2) {
    ...
    async.waterfall([
        async.apply(self.a.f.bind(self.a), arg1, arg2),
        function(data, callback) {
            async.each(data, function(d, callback) {
                async.waterfall([
                    async.apply(self.b.f.bind(self.b), d),
                    self.c.f.bind(self.c),
                    self.d.f.bind(self.d),
                    self.e.f.bind(self.f)
                ], function(err, results) {
                    if (err) {
                        ...
                    }
                    callback();
                });
            }, function(err) {
                callback(err, data);
            });
        }
    ], function (err, result) {
        ...
    });
};
```

Now I know I could separate a-lot of what's going on in here to separate functions, but it's a pipeline of streamlined action passing data from one another after the previous has finished, so I wish to keep it like this instead for example separate the function `function(data, callback) {...}` with a name like BCDEpipeline.
Anyway, my problem is that I do some assertions based on the done callback of the first `async.waterfall()` done function, problem is it gets called later (deferred) even tho I stubbed a, b, c, d, and e functions already and made them yield the next callback immediately. Note that I can't just stub `async.waterfall()` and make it yield its done callback because I'll be left with crucial branches of the code untested (The inner done callbacks of the `async.each()` and the second `async.waterfall()`.
I've tried to use sinon fake timers and used `this.clock.tick(0);` after invoking the `MyClass.prototype.pipeline()` function like so:

```
var obj = new MyClass();
obj.pipeline(5, 3);
this.clock.tick(0);
/* assertions */
...
```

But even so the assertions parts are being executed before any done function is being called. I tried to dig into the async library code to see how it calls its done functions be it's too much of a headache and I couldn't figure out why even tho the done callbacks calls are deferred and with the sinon fake timers, my assertion code is still executing first.
If I use some nested `setImmediate()` calls it works fine, but that's the worst solution for this problem.

Comment: What is all the `.bind` for? Is that your actual code or are you shortening something for this question?

Comment: @clay I use bind to call make the context the instances themselves, This is the code stripped out from the irrelevant parts, everywhere you see `...` is the irrelevant parts. also all the names are fictive (a, b, c, d, e, f, arg1, arg2 etc..)

Answer (score 0):

You left out a lot of stuff so it is hard to tell what this is supposed to do.  Mostly to be honest this looks like noise to me although thats not your fault.

If you don't actually need to do lots of IO in parallel then here is what I suggest.  Switch to ES2017 and babel.  Use classes with @autobind or syntax like:

```
class Test {
  constructor(testB) {
    this.testB = testB;
  }

  fuzz = async x => x+1;

  async foo = (bar) => {
    try {
      const result = await this.testB.blah(bar);
      return await this.fuzz(result);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  async fizz = (bars) => await Promise.all(bars.map(this.foo));
}
```

Then use `ava` for testing.  This way you have a clean way (`await`) to handle basic flow for async functions with a loop and async testing, and your methods' `this` will always point to your instances.

Comment: Unfortunately I use alot of I/O, and switching to babel now is too much of work right now, that I can't afford right now

Comment: OK, just to clarify I meant I/O in parallel, because it seemed like you were trying to do one I/O at a time rather than a bunch concurrently.

Comment: Oh I see you have an async.each in there which is the parallel part.  I would make it a separate function with a try catch inside Promise.all.  Anyway, maybe down the line you can investigate that when you have time for babel etc..  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was a bug in older version according to the following issues I guess:
https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/609 
https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/106

Although they're pretty old and I've used newer version, I've just updated my dependencies and it's now working fine.